# Sony PS Move for the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, playstation

I figured that using PS Move in the browser will be horribly complicated and would probably consume a lot of time. That's why I'd be glad for any kind of assistance: Does anyone have experience with using the PS Move for the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: While I think that would make an extremely interesting project, this question doesn't fit on stack overflow, I'm afraid. it's just too broad..

Comment: where else could I post it?

Comment: You could try gamedev.stackexchange.com, or maybe at a dedicated PS Move forum if there is one